# Filter an array during an arrow function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, puppeteer, arrow-functions

I'm using Node's Puppeteer library to scrape a [website's](https://fiis.com.br/resumo/) table.

During the **scraping**, it returns two arrays, one containing all rows and columns of said table and the second array just contains the first column of the table. I don't know why this happens and couldn't fix this issue.

This is the code I'm using to scrape the table:

```js
var result = await page.$$eval('tbody > tr', rows => {
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
        const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
        const arr = Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
        if (arr.length <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        return arr;
    });
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to filter this second table out of the resulting array, but, I assume that since the arrow function is already doing it's thing, simply calling `return` will result in a null value inside the array. I don't want that, since the array has double the amount of values because of this issue.

I can filter out the null values using this code:

```js
var filtered = result.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null;
});
```

But in doing so I'm iterating the array a second time just to filter out the null values, that's double the amount of time taken to execute my routine.

My question here is: How to filter out these rows with a column count equal to or less than 1?

Edit: Even though I accepted James' answer, I should mention that the real fix to my problem was pointed out by Barmar in the comment section, I should've evaluated the page using `table#filter--result-table-resumo > tbody > tr`, thus filtering out the second unwanted table.

Here is the final code:

```js
var result = await page.$$eval('table#filter--result-table-resumo > tbody > tr', rows => {
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
        const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
        return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
    });
});
```

Comment: `return;` is equivalent to `return undefined;`, not `return null;`

Comment: I don't see anything that returns just the first column of the table? Are you talking about the header row of the table?

Comment: Minor quibble: Puppeteer is made by Google, not by Node.

Comment: It shouldn't be the header row, since that's in `thead`, not `tbody`. So I'm not sure where you're getting double array elements from.

Comment: @Barmar nope, when I run `page.eval$$` it returns two arrays, one with all rows and columns and one with all the rows with just the values of the first column.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's ok, I just mentioned Node because it is a library that runs on node, but I can see how that's irrelevant to the case.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `Array.from()`. `$$eval()` converts the NodeList to an array before passing it to the callback function.

Comment: There are two tables on the page, so `tbody > tr` is selecting rows from both of them. Can you use a more specific selector to process just the table you're interested in?

Comment: Where is this second table? Also, I tried my best to filter out but `tbody > tr` was the only way I managed to get the rows, any Idea how I can filter out just the table I want?

Comment: @Barmar even though James offered a solution to my problem, I would still like to find out where is this second table you mentioned and how I could better filter it out. Thanks for all the help so far tho.

Comment: You can find them in Developer Tools. `<table id="filter--result-table-resumo" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%;" role="grid"><thead><tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">` and `<table class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer DTFC_Cloned" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" role="grid">`

Comment: @Barmar ohhhh, I see. One of the tables is the header and the other one contains the rows.
But how would I filter out during `$$eval()`? I tried `#filter--result-table-resumo` but it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: `table#filter--result-table-resumo > tbody`

Comment: Oh God, I just needed to add `table` before the id? That would've fixed the issue since the beginning. Thanks a lot for the clarification though, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.from is designed to return an array of some exact length, it's not meant for filtering out rows, for that you need array.filter.

```
Array.from(rows).filter(row => row.querySelectorAll('td').length > 1);
```

As @Barmar points out I missed your mapping.  Rather than using .filter and .map (you've pointed out efficiency is important) you can combine those using a `.reduce` to do both operations in one step:

```
Array.from(rows).reduce((acc, row) => {
    const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    if (columns.length > 1) {
      acc.push(Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText));
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Comment: But he also wants to return an array of just the `textContents`, that's why he's using the callback function of `Array.from()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, know I know how to filter out these rows.
Also, I can notice how much the performance is better now.